"Change operation canceled by user" => what does Telerik OpenAccess mean by that?
I'm working on an application, based on another application, and both are based on Telerik OpenAccess for reading an SQL-Server database.
Regularly, my customer is experiencing the following exception:
Telerik.OpenAccess.OpenAccessException: Change operation canceled by user.
   at OpenAccessRuntime.ExceptionWrapper.Throw()
   at OpenAccessRuntime.DataObjects.PCStateMan.handleException(Exception x)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.DataObjects.PCStateMan.SetField[T](PersistenceCapable _pc, Int32 field, T currentValue, T newValue)
   at App1.Server.Core.Domain.CommandOrderPart.OpenAccessEnhancedSet_status(CommandOrderPart owner, OrderStatus value)
   at App1.Server.Core.Domain.CommandOrderPart.set_Status(OrderStatus value)
   at App2.Helpers.ExtensionMethods.SetStatus(CommandOrderPart orderPart, String status) in C:\Source1.cs:line 47
   at App2.Manager.RequestOrderStatus(JbtOrder order) in C:\Source2.cs:line 668 
Telerik.OpenAccess.OpenAccessException: Change operation canceled by user.
   at OpenAccessRuntime.ExceptionWrapper.Throw()
   at OpenAccessRuntime.DataObjects.PCStateMan.handleException(Exception x)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.DataObjects.PCStateMan.SetField[T](PersistenceCapable _pc, Int32 field, T currentValue, T newValue)
   at App1.Server.Core.Domain.CommandOrderPart.OpenAccessEnhancedSet_status(CommandOrderPart owner, OrderStatus value)
   at App1.Server.Core.Domain.CommandOrderPart.set_Status(OrderStatus value)
   at App2.Helpers.ExtensionMethods.SetStatus(CommandOrderPart orderPart, String status) in C:\Source1.cs:line 47
   at App2.Manager.RequestOrderStatus(JbtOrder order) in C:\Source2.cs:line 668

What does this mean exactly "Change operation canceled by user"? Ok, I understand that my applications want to set a status (which is a "change operation"), but who is the user, creating that Exception? Can I get more information from the database? Which table or view or diagnostic? ...?
decompiling Telerik OpenAccess DLL**
After decompiling Telerik OpenAccess DLL, I have found two instances of Change operation canceled by user:

File "DisconnectedStateManager.cs":

    private ChangeEventArgs FireChanging(
      object pc,
      int field,
      object oldV,
      object newV)
    {
      ChangeEventArgs ev = new ChangeEventArgs(pc, this.cmd.getFieldName(field), oldV, newV, this.state == (short) 4, true);
      this.repository.tracker.FireChanging(ev);
      return !ev.Cancel ? ev : throw new OpenAccessException("Change operation canceled by user.", true);
    }


File ".../SPI/TrackingImpl.cs":

    /// <summary>Raises the Changing event.</summary>
    /// <remarks>Not intended for application use.</remarks>
    /// <param name="ev">The event to raise.</param>
    public void FireChanging(ChangeEventArgs ev)
    {
      if (this.evChanging == null)
        return;
      this.evChanging(this.owner, ev);
      if (ev.Cancel)
        throw new OpenAccessException("Change operation canceled by user.", true);
    }

PcStateMan.cs:
In "PcStateMan.cs", the following can be seen in handleException(...):
    private void handleException(Exception x)
    {
      if (BindingSupportImpl.Instance.isOwnException(x))
        throw new ExceptionWrapper(x).Throw();
      throw BindingSupportImpl.Instance.internally(x.Message, x).Throw();
    }

This means that the condition BindingSupportImpl.Instance.isOwnException(x) is true (whatever that means).
Edit: timeout of application's DB timeout:
In case a timeout is configured, for App1 and/or App2, this can happen (just imagine that App1.....CommandOrderPart.Set() takes too long while App2 has a DB timeout setting, this might already cause the issue). Where can I find those timeout settings?
Edit: proposal to find the SQL-statement, causing this situation
Apparently, the problem occurs when the status of a App1.....CommandOrderPart is changed. An SQL-trace can be created, monitoring all transactions, performed on that object, as follows:
DECLARE @TraceID INT;
DECLARE @MaxFileSize BIGINT = 50; -- File size limit in MB
DECLARE @TraceFilePath NVARCHAR(256) = N'C:\SQLTraces\Trace_OrderPart'; -- Base trace file path

-- Step 1: Create a new trace
EXEC sp_trace_create 
    @traceid = @TraceID OUTPUT,
    @options = 2, -- File rollover enabled
    @tracefile = @TraceFilePath,
    @maxfilesize = @MaxFileSize,
    @stoptime = NULL; -- No automatic stop

-- Step 2: Set events to capture
-- Add events to monitor SQL statements and related information
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16,  1, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) TextData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16,  4, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) TransactionId
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16,  9, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 10, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) ApplicationName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 11, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) LoginName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 12, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) SPID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 13, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 14, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) StartTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 15, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) EndTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 20, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) Severity
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 23, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) Success
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 25, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) IntegerData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 27, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) EventClass
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 31, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) Error Number
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 34, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) ObjectName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 49, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) RequestID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 55, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) IntegerData2

EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40,  1, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) TextData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40,  4, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) TransactionId
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40,  9, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 10, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) ApplicationName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 11, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) LoginName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 12, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) SPID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 13, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 14, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) StartTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 15, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) EndTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 20, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) Severity
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 23, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) Success
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 25, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) IntegerData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 27, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) EventClass
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 31, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) Error Number
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 34, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) ObjectName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 49, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) RequestID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 55, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) IntegerData2

EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41,  1, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) TextData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41,  4, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) TransactionId
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41,  9, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 10, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) ApplicationName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 11, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) LoginName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 12, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) SPID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 13, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 14, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) StartTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 15, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) EndTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 20, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) Severity
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 23, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) Success
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 25, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) IntegerData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 27, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) EventClass
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 31, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) Error Number
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 34, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) ObjectName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 49, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) RequestID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 55, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) IntegerData2

-- Step 3: Set a filter for the table CommandOrderParts
EXEC sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 55, 0, 6, N'dbo.CommandOrderParts'; -- ObjectName filter

-- Optional: Add a filter for ApplicationName to capture specific applications
EXEC sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 0, 6, N'File_App1'; -- Filter for File_App1.dll
EXEC sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 1, 6, N'File_App2'; -- Filter for File_App2.dll

-- Step 4: Start the trace
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1; -- Start the trace

-- Step 5: Stop the trace
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 0; -- Stop the trace

Obviously, I start executing this SQL script until step 4. If I want the script to stop, I launch step 5.
Oh, before I forget: the script I first found contained other values for the events. I ran the SQL query SELECT @@VERSION and as the result was Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31-GDR) (KB5029376) ..., I decided to go to this page in order to get the events' definitions:

Edit concerning deadlock-sensitivity
Just for your information: the application seems to be deadlock-sensitive: In a timeframe of not even six months, I have found 213 deadlock-related exceptions like this one:
2024-10-28 12:53:31.5199 | Error | App1.RaiseConnectionFailed | Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.sql.SQLException: Transaction (Process ID 76) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 76) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Intellitrace.Read(DbDataReader reader, String id)
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.Runtime.Logging.LoggingDbDataReader.Read()
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.Adonet2Generic.Impl.ResultSetImp.next()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.Adonet2Generic.Impl.ResultSetImp.next()
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.fetch.FetchResultImp.rsNext()
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.fetch.FetchResultImp.hasNext()  


https://www.reddit.com/r/MailDevNetwork/comments/1h0nnsz/comprehending_telerik_openaccesss_change/

Does the exception object have any more detail in InnerException? It looks from https://www.reddit.com/r/MailDevNetwork/comments/1h0nnsz/comprehending_telerik_openaccesss_change/ to be a concurrency exception, so someone else modified the row underneath you.

@Charlieface: what do you mean by "the row underneath you"? Do you mean that modifications of two subsequent records in a database table can interrupt with each other?

After you loaded the row and before you saved it again, someone else modified the same row.

The bounty text just points to a clone of this question on [dba.se]. Cross Posting is frowned upon at best, and this bounty here feels more like it's to point users at your [dba.se] question, rather than answer the question here. If you are bountying this question, surely you should be bountying the more complete qusetion on [dba.se] and deleting this one. Otherwise take the time to complete this question, and delete the other. If the 2 are related, all the inforamtion to answer this question should be in this question.

Also, please don't put edit headings in your post; we can see what's changed in the revision history if needed.

@ThomA: I understand that cross posting is not a good thing, but try to see the issue from my side: my application is using a library, who is reading a database. My application is not working, due to a problem in that library. Asking on StackOverflow seems not ok, because it's not reproducible, and asking on dba is not good, because from their point of view, it's an application problem, not a dba one. So I decided to ask the question and bounty it on both websites. (Seen the size of my reputation I believe you can cut me some slack :-) )

@ThomA: I also disagree with your statement about "edit headings": those headings show the life of a post: it can start with a "simple" question, but the author learns more and more about the subject, adds that information to the question, and after a while the question itself becomes a treasure of information. Nothing wrong with that.

The answer I link to is not mine, @Dominique . If you disagree with the stance, you should downvote the linked answer, however, there's a reason it's community consensus to not have them. All those "edit" headings are noise, and meaningless; if i'm reading your post for the first time, I don't care that you edited it 9 times, and neither will anyone else; what matters is the current state of the post. If you want to add headings, that's fine, but use a meaningful one, or just split your post into sections with horizontal lines.

Hard to say what the issue is, has this error always been there, or what has changed from when it worked? Did you introduce threads, triggers or other things? Did you try running trace / wireshark. Is change generated from gui somewhere? And what does the code which sets field look like

The problem occurs sometimes, without clear reasons. As far as I know there are no other warnings/errors/Exceptions, neither in our applications' logfiles, neither in the Windows logs, ..., but when it happens, it does cause quite serious harm: automated vehicles stop doing what they should be doing, causing production delays. And I'm a bit reluctant about XEvent Profiling as this creates big logfiles while the problem sometimes only happen once a month.

But if it's just an exception, can't you simply retry the operation? Or is there actual data damage occuring

@siggemannen: the application is a server application, managing a warehouse, where automated vehicles drive around with products. When the problem happens, the vehicle just stops whatever it is doing and blocks the processes in the warehouse. As it's a server application, retrying an operation (like clicking a button) is not applicable. We might find a way to force a retry, but we prefer trying to understand why the problem happens.

I ment something like: while retrycnt++ < 5 { try{setStatus(...); break;} catch(Exception ex) {} } but yeah, i don't know, you keep mentioning LOP_ABORT_XACT but i'm pretty sure that will never occur here. Just try tracing what happens when you call "update" and see what telerik does perhaps

The public FireChanging method invokes evChanging with ChangeEventArgs. It is likely the method sets ChangeEventArgs.Cancel to true to indicate the old/new values are different (a concurrency violation) in order to avoid the race condition and silently overwrite existing database values. The change operation cancelled by user message is a bit misleading in this case. A better message would be something like Operation cancelled because data was changed by another user.
Concurrency issues are a matter of timing and can be problematic to troubleshoot. You need to have application logs and/or SQL tracing detailed enough to correlate the error with requests that try to modify the same data at the same time. The resolution may require changes to the application (e.g. allow user to refresh/retry) or process engineering to avoid attempts to modify the same row concurrently.

Thanks a lot for this clear explanation. However my whole idea started with this, and I had understood that such a situation (two applications/threads, trying to modify the same information) would cause LOP_ABORT_XACT in the transaction logs of the database, but I don't see any of those. (see "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79237417" for another description of the same problem)

Can you check the last edit of my question (about the sp_trace)? I have found such a file and did some editing, but as I'm a complete newbie in those things, I prefer a more experienced person checking this script before risking breaking my customer's system. Thanks a lot in advance.

In case we are dealing here with a race condition, wouldn't we get a Telerik.OpenAccess.Exceptions.OptimisticVerificationException?

@Dominique, the trace script create a legacy server-side SQL trace. See this article for details. I wouldn't expect a significant performance impact since it's filtered to limit the events. Also add the Attention event (under Errors and Warnings category). The Attention indicates the client API canceled the query because the timeout specified on the SQL command object was exceeded.

Also ,be sure to log the @TraceID returned by sp_trace_create so the trace can be later stopped (EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 0) and deleted (EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 2). You'll need to delete the trace files manually.

I've updated my script, but the simple basis keeps on giving problems: I create a trace file (even without anything inside it), and when I try to open it (using SQL Server Profiler) I get the error message "Failed to open a file. Access is denied.".

@Dominique, try running Profiler as Administrator.

Thanks. I managed restarting SSMS as administrator.

This will be my last comment for today. I've finally managed getting the script to start and to generate a *.trc file, but that *.trc file contains the modifications, done on all objects (it seems like the EXEC sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 34, 0, 6, N'dbo.CommandOrderParts'; -- ObjectName filter is not taken into account). In top of that, the "ObjectName" is not present as a column.

Ok. In the meantime I've understood that the script I'm now working on is to be handled by SQL-Server Profiler (I thought this tool was ment for analysing the resulting *.trc files, but it can also be used for creating the corresponding script. This gives me enough help to get further on my own. If I have more problems, they will most probably be for the dba.stackexchange.com website, not for here. Thanks a lot for your assistance and have fun with the bounty :-)

@Dominique, be aware the legacy Profiler SQL Trace is deprecated in favor of Extended Events (XE). which is redundant and also has a bit of a learning curve. Consider becoming familiar with XE tracing for future tracing needs.

Thanks for the advise, but I've started using the stored procedure thing as the XEvent Profiler seems not to have any filtering mechanism: you can launch a session and choose the columns which will be displayed, but I don't see the possibility to perform any filtering, so I fear my profiler results becoming that big that I might even cause problems in the database environment.

@Dominique, XE does have filtering. In the SSMS UI, server side filters are available as a tab on the event session properties page and also in XE DDL scripts.  The SSMS XE viewer also has client filtering to limit the events more for ad-hoc needs.
